# Why i can console property inside prototype while invoking a function

Tags: javascript, function, inheritance, prototype

hi i am very beginner in javascript i write a simple code to learn javascript prototype inheritance

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};
Person.prototype.isPerson = true;

var person = new Person('Smith');
// DOT(person,'name') should return Smith
// DOT(person,'isPerson') should true;
var DOT = function(obj, pro) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(pro)) {
    console.log(obj[pro]);
  } else {
    //  return DOT(obj.__proto__,pro)
  }
};

console.log(person['isPerson']);

DOT(person, 'name');
DOT(person, 'isPerson');
```

in this code I have one doubt in the last line DOT function invoked will not return true but I can able to return true while console console.log(person['isPerson']) why is that..?

Comment: Prototypal inheritance searches the "prototype chain" to look for a property. That's why `person['isPerson']` gives you the value. It looks at `person`, doesn't find it, so then it looks at `Person.prototype`, and finds it. That also explains why `hasOwnProperty()` gives `false`. The `isPerson` is not directly on the object; it's on `Person.prototype`.

Comment: Wow thanks very much